# Зачем нужен finally?

Tags: java, исключения

Допустим есть такой код

```
try {
    parseJson(response.json);
}
catch(JSONException e) {
    Log.v("err", e.toString());
}
finally {
    hideLoadingProgress();
}
```

`response.json` это `JSONObject`, приходит с сервера. В `try` я передаю его методу на обработку, в `catch` вывожу ошибки в логи, в `finally` я скрываю индикатор загрузки. Тоесть, не важно, успешно ли завершится парсинг или нет, индикатор в любом случае убираем. Но зачем `finally`? Я же могу сделать так

```
try {
    parseJson(response.json);
}
catch(JSONException e) {
    Log.v("err", e.toString());
}
hideLoadingProgress();
```

P.S Не пробовал так, вдруг все упадет :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Во втором случае если в методе `parseJson` произойдёт, например, `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, то метод `hideLoadingProgress` вызван не будет. Даже если вы отловите исключение где-то выше в коде, индикатор загрузки так и будет отображаться.

Кроме такого "неожиданного" исключения возможна ещё ситуация "неожиданно" появившегося в блоках `try` и `catch` оператора `return`, который, при помещении вызова `hideLoadingProgress` после `finally`, опять-таки испортит скрытие индикатора.

В блок `finally` помещают код, который гарантированно должен быть вызван (кроме случаев завершения работы JVM или текущего потока посреди блоков `try` и `catch`). Таким кодом, например, является закрытие использованных в блоке `try` ресурсов для предотвращения утечек. В случае UI - например, индикатор загрузки.

Примерно то же самое можно прочитать в [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html).

Answer (score 3):

Если у вас произойдет исключение, которе вы не обрабатываете (например unchecked), то произойдет выход и метода. Следовательно весь последующий код будет пропущен.

А блок `finally` выполнится перед выходом из блока `try/catch`.